# Take in a Java ResultSet the return from a plpgsql function

Tags: java, postgresql, function, resultset, plpgsql

Here we don't have one select query to take with getString the variables.So how can i take the result from just a return ?

```
create or replace function takeSomething()
    returns text AS
    $$
BEGIN
    return 'Ok';
END;    
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Java code:

```
ResultSet result;
result=Pstatement.executeQuery("Select takeSomething()");
result.next();
```

Comment: after `result.next()` use `result.getString(1)` - as with every other select statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ResultSet result;
result=Pstatement.executeQuery("Select takeSomething()");
result.next();
System.out.println(result.getString(1));
```

as with every other select statement.

BY –>  a_horse_with_no_name